# how to allow employees to post reviews for candidates

Tags: custom, object

i'm creating a Recruiting app and i want to know how to how to allow employees to post reviews for candidates

Comment: Is this question about the Recruiting App one creates in the [Force.com Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) also referred to as "Creating on Demand Applications"?

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of ways you can do something like this, but the most important thing to consider first are what the other requirements of the application will be.

- Will all of your employees be Salesforce users? For the purposes of this answer, I will assume yes.
- Will the feedback on candidates be largely unstructured (comments only) or will there be quantifiable metrics (scale of 1-5, for example)?

  - If it will be totally unstructured, you might be able to accomplish this by just using the Chatter feed on the Candidate record.
  - If there will be ratings in addition to comments, you'll probably need a child object to allow multiple people to leave feedback on the same candidate.
- Who should be able to provide feedback?

  - If anyone with access to the Candidate should be allowed to leave feedback, it might suffice to create a "Feedback" object with a Master-Detail relationship to the Candidate record. Users can provide feedback by creating a new Feedback record via the related list or (probably more user-friendly) a Chatter Publisher action.
  - If you want to assign specific reviewers to a candidate, the same solution above generally applies, but I'd suggest creating the Feedback records as reviewers are assigned, rather than allowing reviewers to create their own. Then, reviewers will visit the record assigned to them, enter their feedback, and submit the record.

Having built a similar solution myself in the past, I would urge you to also consider the following:

- You will probably want to limit the number of times a reviewer can add feedback to a candidate (usually, I'd assume this should be only once).
- You may want to restrict whether new feedback can be left based on the status of the candidate's application (no more feedback needed if candidate is hired or rejected).
- You may consider locking feedback records after they are submitted to prevent changes. My personal preference for doing this is by auto-submitting a record to an approval process.